# Terminating a shell script bar from a script foo

Tags: bash, scripting, kill

I have a script `foo` which, if provided an argument `start`, starts, among other things a script `bar` in the background and exits - `bar` contains an infinite loop.

At a later stage, I want to call `foo`  with argument `stop` and I would like that script `bar`, which still runs in the background stops running.

What is the text book way of achieving this?

Comment: What happens when you run `foo start` and an instance of `bar` is already running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case multiple `bar` instances can run simultaneously, and `foo stop` should stop/kill them all, use [`pkill`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pgrep):

```
$ pkill bar
```

to kill all processes named `bar`.

In case only one `bar` instance is allowed to run, a solution with a "pidfile" would be viable.

In `foo`:

```
pidfile=/var/run/bar.pid

if ((start)); then
    if [ -e "$pidfile" ]; then
        echo "$pidfile exists."
        # clean-up, or simply abort...
        exit 1
    fi
    bar &
    echo $! >"$pidfile"
fi

if ((stop)); then
    if [ ! -e "$pidfile" ]; then
        echo "$pidfile not found."
        exit 1
    fi
    kill "$(<"$pidfile")"
    rm -f "$pidfile"
fi
```

Comment: Nice solution, thanks! Once question: in the stop section, shouldn't we delete the pidfile as the last instruction? Otherwise we would always end up in the echo "$pidfile exists." case

Answer (score 0):

[There are better ways to do what you're trying to do I believe](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) if your host has systemd or initd there are frameworks already in place to have long running jobs with start/stop capabilities.

If you must do this independent of those or other useful tools I would solve it like this:

When you call `foo start` store the PID of the newly spawned `bar` process in a file, lets call it `pidfile`. This can be a newline delimited list of PIDs as well.

When you call `foo stop` use `pkill -F pidfile` to kill all running processes with PIDs matching those in `pidfile`

Alternatively you could use `pkill` to dicover the PIDs of all processes matching certain criteria when you called `foo stop`. This might be easier, but may also be more fragile.